# Operator `-` is amigues on operands of type `Vector2` and `Vector3`

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

This is my second time posting about this code as I keep running into errors as I use it. I originally make this from a tutorial but idk what is wrong with it.
I have not really been able to try anything as I am a newbie dev and just don't know what to do

```
public class Draggable : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector2 difference = Vector2.zero;
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        difference = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
    }

    private void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        transform.position = (Vector2) Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - difference;
    }
}
```

Here is a picture of the error:

[image]

Comment: Can you put the error as text into your question via the edit feature?

Comment: I'll try, 1 sec...

Comment: Sorry that took a bit but here are some errors
Assets\THEOTHERTEST.cs(10,9): error CS0103: The name 'difference' does not exist in the current context
Assets\THEOTHERTEST.cs(10,22): error CS0034: Operator '-' is ambiguous on operands of type 'Vector2' and 'Vector3'
Assets\THEOTHERTEST.cs(15,94): error CS0103: The name 'difference' does not exist in the current context

Comment: If that text is the error. Then the above code is not what you have

Comment: **[Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)**

Answer (score 1):

Unity has implicit operator conversion between `Vector2` and `Vector3`.

```
Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition)
```

returns a `Vector3`.

```
difference
```

is a `Vector2`.

`-` is only implemented with either `Vector2 - Vector2` or `Vector3 - Vector3`.

=> The compiler doesn't know whether

- it should rather convert the `difference` to a `Vector3` and use the `Vector3 - Vector3` operator
- or it should convert the result of `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition)` to a `Vector2` and rather use the `Vector2 - Vector2` operator

Long story short it seems you would want the second option so you need to explicit type cast not the result of the `-` but rather

```
(Vector2) Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition)
```

so

```
transform.position = ((Vector2) Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition)) - difference;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `Vector2` cast to

```
transform.position = ((Vector2) Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition)) - difference;
```

Note the extra pair of wrapping parenthesis.

What is happening is that originally you were doing

```
transform.position = (Vector2) (Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - difference);
```

This didn't work because `ScreenToWorldPoint` returns a `Vector3` while `difference` is a `Vector2`. Now you will be casting the result of `ScreenToWorldPoint` to a `Vector2` before the subtraction operation.

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/984082746932600942/1012506046482354207/unknown.png it added another error to the current 3...

Comment: Please stop posting images, just copy the error to the comment section.

Comment: Although looking at that error, it looks like you are now messing up your project's build setup. Stop adding new files and just change the original file.

Comment: Or you have some kind of typo in your file.